# Problem with switch

Tags: actionscript-3, string, switch-statement

My problem is that I can't (don't know) make work my switch. Here in my first case, I input `"hache"`, and it doesn't pass trough. Strangely, in my `trace(traget);` [Object hache] or [Object extincteur] (depending on wich mc I click on) comes out... Why does it don't go trough the first case? I have no clue. I tried removing the " ".

```
package cem
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class actionObjets{

        /*--inventaire--*/
        private static var inventaireHache:Boolean = false;
        private static var inventaireExtincteur:Boolean = false;

        private var objetClique:MovieClip;

        public function actionObjets(target) {
            this.objetClique = target;
            switch(objetClique){
                case "hache":
                    inventaireHache = true;
                    ajouterInventaire(objetClique);
                    break;
                case "extincteur":
                    inventaireExtincteur = true;
                    ajouterInventaire(objetClique);
                    break;
            }
            trace(target);
        }
        private function ajouterInventaire(objetEnlever):void{
            objetClique.parent.removeChild(objetClique);
            trace(inventaireHache + " - Hache");
            trace(inventaireExtincteur + " - Extincteur");
        }

    }

}
```

btw, target is the movieClip I clicked on a.k.a. Object extincteur, or Object hache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `objetClique` isn't a string. You probably want to do something like `switch (objetClique.name)`.

If you want to understand what's going on, rewrite the code this way:

```
if (objetClique == "hache") {
  // ...
} else if (objetClique == "extincteur") {
  // ...
}
```

I hope this illustrates more clearly why the switch doesn't work. `objetClique` couldn't be equal to the string `"hache"`, *because it's not a string*. From the looks of it `objetClique` refers to a `DisplayObject` and they have a property called `name`, which is what you want to compare:

```
if (objetClique.name == "hache") {
  // ...
} else if (objetClique.name == "extincteur") {
  // ...
}
```

that code would work, and it's equivalent to a switch that looks like this:

```
switch (objetClique.name) {
  case "hache":
    // ...
    break;
  case "extincteur":
    // ...
    break;
 }
```

Comment: Hummmm! That's pretty much what I need. Now, my problem is: it traces instance7, instance8 etc... Is there a way to name the instances with real names?

Comment: nvm... I just did some research. whatiwant.name = "nameiwant". Haha what a noob I am! Thx a lot!! You're a great help! I accept your answer! hehe.

Comment: If this is Flash you can click on the element on the stage and fill in the name in the name field in one of the inspectors. Otherwise you can just to `myDisplayObject.name = "helloworld"` wherever you have a display object you want to name.